# Mockup Editor - Free tool to easily add arrows, callouts, etc

Tags: editor, screenshot, mockups

I've been using [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/demos/mockups/Mockups.html) to create mockups.  I'm using the trial version, so I have all screens in one mockup instead of multiple files.  I want to send an export of these mockups to my team so they can comment on them.  They need to be able to easily add arrows, callouts, text, etc.  I know  you can do some of that in Balsamiq, but it isn't really made for these types of comments.  I have used Paint.net and added these in separate layers, but it isn't the most easy to use application for some non-technical people.  I like the editor in [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp) as it easily allows mark up an image, but that is a paid app and I am looking for a free tool (that runs on Windows).

This tool doesn't necessarily need a screenshot capture tool as there are [plenty of options available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183/screenshot-taking-tools), but this wouldn't preclude a tool.

The things I would like to be able to easily do are:

- Add arrows to show what button was clicked to move from one screen to another
- Add callout text to offer suggestions to reword a section or move an item
- Use different color/size markup items

I've found [Pencil](http://www.evolus.vn/Pencil/), but that seems like overkill - I don't need full image editing, just the ability for someone to quickly and easily provide feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try [ForeUI](http://www.foreui.com), if you like it, please drop me a mail to vivi[at]foreui.com, I can send you a license for free :-)

Comment: @Vivi, you wouldn't happen to be the boss of the company now, would you? :)

Comment: Nice tool, but a bit slow working. A native port would be better instead of Java. I prefer "Pencil" this days.

Comment: @melaos: I am one of the cofounders :-)
@devarni: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Not free but if you already have MS Office with OneNote installed it's great for stuff like this imho. I think there's a free reader as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want quick and easy feedback use a pen and paper.

Print the screens and hand them out those on the team that need a say in the UI.  Have them markup to their heart's content and hand them back to you.  I know it makes me sound like a luddite, but it really is the most effective way.

Comment: It is a distributed team, and that would require scanning and emailing of all of the various screenshots back and forth. It's possible, but adds overhead.  Plus, new tools and gadgets are fun.

Comment: Having a distributed team makes it more interesting.  You could export your screens as images, then create a google document (docs.google.com) that the team could all edit.  If you make it a presentation type, they can insert arrow images (and color code them for clarity).  They could use the "speaker notes" section to make textual comments.